# Reload Table View Except for One Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a table view containing searchable data, and one cell which contains an editable textField (editable with a pickerView).  I am using the pickerView to select the section of the tableview to be displayed.  However, when a new row is selected in the pickerView, I don't want the pickerView to be dismissed, which is what happens when I use

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

I've tried the following to solve the problem, attempting to reload the table except for the cell containing the textField:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
NSIndexSet *toReload = [[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:1];
if (row == 0)
{
    self.selectedDepartmentField.text = @"All";
    toReload = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 13)];
}
else
{
    self.selectedDepartmentField.text = [self.departments objectAtIndex:(row - 1)];
}
[self.tableView reloadSectionIndexTitles];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadSections:toReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

This crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x28)

How should I go about reloading the data in the table to keep the pickerView active?

Comment: How many sections are in your table?

Comment: When the pickerView selects row 0, there will be 14 sections.  When it is on any other row, there will be 2 sections

Comment: Which line is triggering the crash?  If necessary, enable the Exceptions breakpoint to find out.

Comment: [self.tableView endUpdates];

Answer (score 1):

Following is one possible approach

1. Get an array of `NSIndexPath` with

   ```
   NSArray *visibleIndexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
   ```
2. Remove the indexpath of the cell with picker from `visibleIndexPaths` .
3. Reload the tableview using following method

   ```
   [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:visibleIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
   ```

This should reload all visible cells other than one with picker.

Comment: This didn't work for me, with the error 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 2, but there are only 2 sections after the update'.  I think this may be because there are fewer rows and sections when the table view updates.